# Why the login page of limesurvey only reload if I try to begin a session?

Tags: limesurvey

I have a problem with my Limesurvey login (Only reload the page)

I got this message in the inspection Firefox page

`---> If you see this you have probably JavaScript deactivated. LimeSurvey does not work without Javascript being activated in the browser!` 
When I went to the logs I didn´t have any information about

¿Someone could help me?

I have this versions of
PHP 7.4
Nginx 1.2
MySQL 8.0.26
Lime 4.2.4

Comment: Lime 4.2.4 ? I would recomen to upgarde to latest v5 o latest 6 at least

Comment: Hello
Thanks for your response, i have this version because it don't have problems with anothers programs that i have. I got the solution changing the user of the folder and give all permissions